# How to manage a private recordset object in its own file

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, subroutine

I have a subroutine to extract the desired records from database. I prefer to envelope the subroutine and its depended objects in a single file and include the file in every page that I need to this subroutine. This is what this subroutine does:

**file name : findJob.asp**

```
sub findJob(id)
   sql="select title from jobs where id=" & id
   rsJob.open sql,objcon
   response.write rsJob("title") & "<br>"
   rsJob.close
end sub
```

As you see there is a recordset object I named it `rsJob`. If I create and dispose this object in `findjob.asp` file, obviously it won't work anymore because I have unset it before I use it. So currently I manage it like this:

**The source of Main.asp:**

```
<!--#include file="findJob.asp"-->
set rsJob= Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
rsJob.CursorType = 2

sql="select * from jobs"
rs.open sql,objcon
   while not rs.eof
      call findJob(rs("id"))
   rs.movenext
   wend
rs.close

set rsJob=nothing
```

As you see I have to set and unset the **rsJob** object is in the `main.asp` (not in `findJob.asp` itself). It seems ugly as it is not related to the `Main.asp` and I have to repeat it in every page I include the subroutine. How do you manage this situation in a clean structure?

**Note:** I don't want to set and unset database objects in every call of subroutine because there may be 1 milion records and obviously I dont want to create a milion of database objects in a simple query.

Comment: How is that OOP, I'm not sure you understand that yourself. Writing a function to return a recordset, does not make the code OO. In fact, Classic ASP doesn't lend itself well to that approach but you can use VBScript `Class` to accomplish this but with some overheads. If you want to write true OO code move to something like VB.Net.

Comment: Seriously after the amount of help you've had on this site and various comments about SQL Injection warnings but you continue to make the same mistakes.

Comment: Thank you @Lankymart But this is just a simple sample to describe my question. This is not a runtime project nor a security question.

Comment: It’s also got nothing to do with OOP techniques so you need another example preferably using the VBScript `Class` statement. Just because it’s a *”simple sample”* doesn’t mean you should skip on using the correct techniques otherwise your just teaching yourself bad habits. The approach using `ADODB.Command` is very different and should be your go to for any querying of a database in Classic ASP.